tcolorbox in multicols extra vertical space between color boxes
I am currently writing checklists using tcolorbox package. For readability and space saving I want to use a 2-column format.
I use a parbox to simulate a table because tabular (and derivative) do not work well in multicolum environments.
I am facing an issue where sometimes an extra vertical space is added between tcolorbox environments (see between checklist 2 and 3)
How can I allow tcolobox to break at the end of the page without adding extra vertical space?
I am using XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024) or This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)
TIA.

MWE:
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}


\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{pgffor}

% Text size
\setlength{\textheight}{25.0cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}


%% Create a simple strut to used by color boxes.
\def\myStrut{\vphantom{Cap}}


\pgfkeys{
  /cl/.cd,
  %% default style for a checklist. The title is added by the
  %% checklist environment.
  checklist/.style = {
    boxrule = 1pt,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt,
    lefttitle=2pt, righttitle=2pt, toptitle=3pt, bottomtitle=3pt,
    coltitle=black,
    sharp corners,
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced,
    colbacktitle = green!20,
    breakable,
    fonttitle={\bfseries\large\sffamily},
    center title,
    enforce breakable = true,
  },
    item left font/.initial = {\bfseries\sffamily},
  %% How to format the right hand side checklist item.
  item right font/.initial = {\bfseries\sffamily},
  %% How to format the fill between LHS and RHS item.
  item fill/.initial = {\color{gray!75}\dotfill},
}

\newenvironment{checklist}[2][]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[%
      /cl/checklist,%
      title=\myStrut#2,%
    ]%
}{%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}%


%% cli output a checklist item.
%%
%%  #1: The checklist configuration
%%  #2: The checklist item (Left hand side)
%%  #2: The checklist value (Right hand side)
%%
%% The output line looks like:
%%
%%    item....................value
%%
\newcommand{\cli}[3][]{%
  \pgfkeys{%
    /cl/.cd,%
    #1,%
  }%
  \parbox%
    %% Make parbox to extend the whole available line. Remove the
    %% framebox separation twice, one for LHS and one for RHS.
    {\linewidth-2\fboxsep}%
    {%
      ~\myStrut{}%
          {\pgfkeysvalueof{/cl/item left font}#2}%
          {\pgfkeysvalueof{/cl/item fill}}%
          {\pgfkeysvalueof{/cl/item right font}#3}}%
}%


\newcommand{\addcl}[2]{
  \begin{checklist}[]{Checklist #1}
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,#2} {
      \cli{item \x}{goal \x}
    }
  \end{checklist}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Unbalanced multicol enviroment}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\addcl{1}{40}
\addcl{2}{30}
\addcl{3}{10}
\addcl{4}{20}
%\addcl{5}{20}
\end{multicols*}

\newpage

\section{Balanced multicol enviroment}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\addcl{1}{40}
\addcl{2}{30}
\addcl{3}{10}
\addcl{4}{20}
%\addcl{5}{20}
\end{multicols}

\newpage

\section{Unalanced multicol}
\multicols{2}
\addcl{1}{40}
\addcl{2}{30}
\addcl{3}{10}
\addcl{4}{20}
%\addcl{5}{20}

\end{document}



I get https://i.sstatic.net/65py3o2B.png if I try your code with pdflatex. Do you actually need an unicode-aware engine?

That would be preferable yes.  And if you look carefully in your output the vertical space between 2 and 3 is not the same as others.

If any of the boxes are unbreakable, you will get big gaps between them.  The usual solution is \raggedbottom.,

@JohnKormylo I did some tests using both \raggedbottom and \raggedcolumns nothing helped. For the record all tcolorbox are breakable.
